# How to change appearance of ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have three main things I want to change with the appearance of a ListView.
1) get rid of horizontal dividers that print between items
2) change font size of test displayed in listview
3) change the padding around each item displayed

It looks like after reading for a while that 2) and 3) should be controlled by changing these properties for the TextView used by the ListView, but I don't yet understand how to do that. Can someone answer these with a little more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Set divider height to 0 --- setDividerHeight(0) and set divider color to transparent --- setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x00FFFFFF))

2) If you're using a list of text views then you can continue using a simple adapter like ArrayAdapter but you will need to create a custom text view. You can add something like this to res/layout
test_text.xml

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize=<SIZE IN SP>
android:textColor="#FFF" />
```

3) Add padding to your textview above

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:padding="5dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize=<SIZE IN SP>
android:textColor="#FFF" />
```

Use your new layout with your ArrayAdapter

```
eg.
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)

ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.test_text, R.id.text, myData);
```

Comment: Just to add, to get rid of the divider in your XML layout, you can set your ListView to have the attribute `android:divider="@null"`.

Comment: This all works.  The key to my issue is I copied a google example program and modified the underlying functionality, but not the GUI, so I haven't had a lot of hands on experience with this, but have read quite a bit.  The main piece I was missing for 2) and 3) is I did recongnize that ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.test_text, R.id.text, myData); is how you set the style for the TextView used by the ListView

Answer (score 2):

All of those can be controlled via styles. [The docs on styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) explain everything you need to do.

In short, you create a style resource - derived from whatever you want to use as your base - where you override all the relevant items, like the divider, the padding the font size.

Then, you either apply that style to your ListView in the XML file, or you create a theme to it and call setTheme() BEFORE you call setContentView().

EDIT: I should mention the obvious answer that kcoppock pointed out - if this is specific to just one element in your layout, just modify that particular element in your layout file.

Comment: This was helpful, even though I choose a different answers as the accepted answer.